# angularjs directive reuse template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a context menu directive in AngularJS. In my web page I have a list of items and each item has a button that opens that context menu.
Since there is only one context menu visible on screen, I would like to create a single menu template and each time a context menu button is clicked, update the template with the seleted item's data.
What I am looking for is a way to reuse a template element.

For example, if I have 1000 items, the template should be created only once for all the elements and not 1000 times. Whenever the user clicks on the trigger button, the directive will recompile the template with the template with the item's data and attach it to the relevant place.

Is this possible in AngularJs? If it is, what is the best way to implement it?

Comment: you can use ng-include

Comment: I just encountered a similar situation. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-include, rather than creating directives all the time:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

You can create a template and then include it in a loop. The logic for updating it with the right content should reside in the controller.

A gotcha, is that you need to pass the template path as a string e.g

`<span ng-include="'partials/folder/includes/my-template.html'"></span>`

Note the single quotes after the double quotes.

Comment: If I have 1000 items, the partial will be added 1000 times! I want it to be created once and for all the 1000 items.

Comment: True, but at some point, something has to generate it. Whether that's some code in a directive doing DOM manipulation or a template. You're talking about "the template should be created only once" but surely in creating that you're going to need to loop 1000 times, same effect. Perhaps I don't quite understand your question...